# Create string from nested object with references to parent keys

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an input like this:

```
{
 a: 'b',
  c: {
    d: 'e',
    f: {
      g: 'h',
      i: 'j'
    }
  }
}
```

How can I output a string like this where it creates a map down to the value of the last child on each initial key no matter how many levels deep:

```
'a=b&c[d]=e&c[f][g]=h&c[f][i]=j'
```

Comment: `but I can't seem to get the deeply nested values to work right.` See `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. `

Comment: What's wrong with `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @BenM doesn't JSON.stringify just return the object as json? I'm not sure how that would create a map like this.

Comment: @sturoid Yes, it does. But I think you have an X-Y problem. Why do you need it in this format specifically?

Comment: I need it to create a map like that back up to the top level parent key. Pretty sure recursion would be the solution but I can't get it to work past 2 levels deep the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, recursion is required, along with Array methods like `map` and `concat` and `join`

```js
var x = {
 a: 'b',
  c: {
    d: 'e',
    f: {
      g: 'h',
      i: 'j'
    }
  }
};
const makePath = (path, key) => path ? `${path}[${key}]` : `${key}`;
const doThings = (obj, path='') => 
    [].concat(...Object.entries(obj)
        .map(([key, value]) => 
            typeof value === 'object' ? doThings(value, makePath(path, key)) : `${makePath(path, key)}=${value}`
        )
    );

console.log(doThings(x).join('&'));
```

Comment: That's such an awesome solution. Thank you :).